# How to use fetchone() instead of fetchall()?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

It works fine with fetchall but I'm trying to figure out how to use fetchone instead. I want to be able to store all user input but only show the last input (the individual user's input). I am using sqlite, python, HTML, and flask.

```
def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('databse.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

# get all users


@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    users = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', users=users)

# add a new user


@app.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']

        if not firstname:
            flash('firstname is required!')
        elif not lastname:
            flash('lastname is required!')
        elif not lastname:
            flash('email is required!')
        else:
            conn = get_db_connection()
            conn.execute('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                         (firstname, lastname, email))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('home2.html')
```

The user should only see their input. This is what I have tried

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    user = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1').fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', user=user)

# add a new user


@app.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']

        if not firstname:
            flash('firstname is required!')
        elif not lastname:
            flash('lastname is required!')
        elif not lastname:
            flash('email is required!')
        else:
            conn = get_db_connection()
            conn.execute('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                         (firstname, lastname, email))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('home2.html')
```

Comment: It's not clear what "I want to be able to store all user input but only show the last input (the individual user's input)" means. Please [edit] your question to explain what you want to do more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe returning the user as a list. Try users=[user] in the render_template.